# Returning PSCustomObject Properties From a Function

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-4.0

I'm making a function that prompts for a choice and, upon selecting that choice, it assigned a value to a returned variable's property via a PSCustomObject.

```
function Select-ChoiceFunction {
    # This generates a simple choice menu #
    $Title = "Title"
    $Info = "Info"
    $choice = echo @("Choice &1", "Choice &2", "Choice &3", "&Cancel")
    [int]$defaultchoice = 3
    $selection = $host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $info, $choice, $defaultchoice)

    # Switch assigns two pieces of data to two variables #
    switch ($selection) {
        0 {
            $var1 = "Data 1"
            $var2 = "Data 2"
            Write-Host "`Choice 1`n"; break
        }
        1 {
            $var1 = "Data 3"
            $var2 = "Data 4"
            Write-Host "`Choice 2`n"; break
        }
        2 {
            $var1 = "Data 5"
            $var2 = "Data 6"
            Write-Host "`Choice 3`n"; break
        }
        default {
            $WarningPreference = "Stop"
            Write-Warning "`nNo Choice Made.`n"
        }
    }

    # Creating PSObject to return Properties from selection outside the Function #
    $Results = [PSCustomObject]@{
        var1 = $var1
        var2 = $var2
    }

    return $Results
}
```

So if I run the scripted commands independently, it works how I want. I select Choice 1 above and checking the variables shows this:

```
$Results.var1 = "Data 1"
$Results.var2 = "Data 2"
```

And so on for each other choice. However, when I wrap it in a function and call it else where, it returns both variables, like so:

```
$Choices = Select-ChoiceFunction
```

Select Choice 1

```
$Results.var1 = "Data 1" "Data 2"
$Results.var2 = "Data 1" "Data 2"
```

I also tried piping `Select-Object` to it like so:

```
$Choices = Select-ChoiceFunction | Select-Object $Results.var1
```

Select Choice 1 returns with:

```
"Data 1" "Data 2"
```

As with above, I'm wanting to call the function and get the variable properties independently. I assume the function is made incorrectly, but am unclear what I need to add in order to return the properties separately.

UPDATE: Answered by Ansgar/TheMadTechnician. I should be calling the properties like this:

```
$Choices = Select-ChoiceFunction
```

Select Choice 1

```
$Choices.var1 = "Data 1" "Data 2"
$Choices.var2 = "Data 1" "Data 2"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When I run your code I get the desired result. Maybe try to start a brand new PowerShell session (especially if you're using ISE) and see if you still get the wrong result.

Comment: For me calling the function threw an error, b/c `$choice` is not of type `[Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]`. After fixing that it worked as expected, though. Please double-check if `$Choices.var1` and `$Choices.var2` really are not holding the correct values.

Comment: You are referencing `$Results.var1` and `$Results.var2` outside of your function, but you should be looking at `$Choices.var1` and `$Choices.var2`.

Comment: Ansgar/TheMadTechnician: That was where I was going wrong. Couldn't see the forest for the trees, apparently. Thanks!

Not sure how to do this, but my question was answered.

Comment: @Admonition no worries; it happens. I voted to close this under the typo/not reproducable reason. These types of questions tend not to be useful for other readers, which is why we haven't posted an answer. I'd recommend just deleting the question; no harm done.

Comment: @briantist While I definitely agree it being a silly mistake, the thinking that it's not useful for readers is baffling. Seeing another person's mistake is immensely helpful, as there been another example of someone making this mistake, I would have not needed to post this question at all.

Comment: @Admonition the reason is a matter of discoverability. Yes, if someone made the same mistake and happened to read your question somehow, they may realize their own, but their situation will be completely different; much as you thought this was an issue about returning objects or array aggregation, someone else's situation will appear to them as an unrelated issue too (because this type of misunderstanding, while common, necessarily leads to asking the wrong question). You can certainly leave it and the community will decide; just offering my perspective on how things work here.

Comment: @Admonition also to be clear: I don't consider this a _bad question_ (I wouldn't downvote it); it's well-formed, includes code, a clear statement of what you tried, the result you received and the expected result. So I certainly don't mean it as criticism and I don't mean to discourage you from asking future questions in any way (quite the opposite).

Comment: @briantist I understand. SE (or other such websites) tend to have a tribal manner they've developed as to how information is transferred. I also have no problem with the post being _closed_ as non-reproducible. My point is that _deleting_ it may be a bit excessive and a waste of me posting a question here where others could see it later on a topic that has little such clear information. 

In the post, the title directly applies to the problem (me incorrectly returning object properties from a function) and it also contains the solution edited in... Nothing much to misunderstand there to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You are referencing $Results.var1 and $Results.var2 outside of your function, but you should be looking at $Choices.var1 and $Choices.var2." – TheMadTechnician